# How to show div based on Beaker session status with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bottle, beaker

Content is loaded in a `main_content` area via jQuery Ajax.

Outside of the `main_content` area is a `login` link.

Clicking on this link loads a form in the `main_content` area which, when submitted, performs login authorisation with Beaker.  On success, an admin page is loaded in the `main_content` area.

I want to change the `login` link to a `logout` link after successful authorisation.

Is there a way to show/hide divs based on session status in Beaker, with something like:

```
if (beaker.session.id) {
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#logout').show();
}
```

I would call this in the jQuery block dealing with successful login and then swap the divs in the block dealing with logout.

**Edit**

In Firebug, in the login `POST` response, I go to `"Cookies" > "Received Cookies"` and can see a listing for:

```
beaker.session.id
```

If I right-click on this link and select `"Use in Command Line"`, the following pops up in the command line area:

```
$p
```

If I then run the following in the Firebug command line area, I get an alert pop up with the specified message:

```
if ($p) {alert("you have an id!")}
```

So I tried to add this to the code that processes the login but I didn't get an alert:

```
<script>
$(document).on("submit","#login", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/login',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(results) {
$("#main_content").html("");
$("#main_content").append(results.content);
href = results.title;
history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
reinit1();
reinit2();
reinit3();
if ($p) { // <-- here is the alert
alert("Yes you have an ID!")
}
}
});
});
</script>
```

I get error:

```
ReferenceError: $p is not defined
```

Comment: post your ajax section and login html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution as to how to access the `beaker.session.id` cookie, so I just created a [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on login success, and then created an if statement which displayed the `logout` link if the newly created login existed (and I'll remove the cookie on logout to reverse the process):

```
<script>
// login processing as shown above
reinit1();
reinit2();
reinit3();
$.cookie('logged-in', "YES", { path: '/'}); // set cookie and assign name and value
if ($.cookie('logged-in') == "YES") { //  check the value of the cookie
$('.login').hide();
$('.logout').show();
}
}
}
});
});
</script>
```